# Setup serverless local environment for AWS using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework

Hi I am using the serverless framework to develop my application and I need to set it up in a local environment I am using API gateway, Lambda, VPC , SNS, SQS, and DB is connected via VPC peering, currently, everytime I am deploying and testing my code and its tedious process and takes 5 mins to deploy, Is there any way to set up a local environment to have everything in one place

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible in theory, but it is not an easy thing to do. There are products like [LocalStack](https://localstack.cloud/features/) that offer exactly this.

*But*, I would not recommend going that route. Ultimately, by design this will always be a huge cat and mouse game. AWS introduces a new feature or changes some minor detail of their implementation and products like LocalStack need to catch up. Furthermore, you will always only get an "approximation" of the "actual cloud". It never won't be a 100% match.

I would think there is a lot of work involved to get products like LocalStack working properly with your setup and have it running well.

Therefore, I would propose to invest the same time into proper developer experience within the "actual cloud". That is what we do: every developer deploys their version of the project to AWS.

This is also not trivial, but the end result is not a "fake version" of the cloud that might or might not reflect the "real cloud".

The key to achieve this is [Infrastructure as code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code) and as much automation as possible. We use [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io) and [Makefiles](https://makefiletutorial.com) which works very well for us. If done properly, we only ever build and deploy what we changed. The result is that changes can be deployed in seconds to AWS and the developer can test the result either through the Makefile itself or using the AWS console.

And another upside of this is, that in theory you need to do all the same work anyway for your continuous deployment, so ultimately you are reducing work by not having to maintain local deployments and cloud deployments.